# Premiere Pro: Simple fade for text?

Tags: premiere, pro

In most video editing softwares I have used, you can

```
- Click Text Object
- Click Button: Fade In/Fade Out
- Done.
```

But in Premiere pro, I have to

```
- Click Text Object
- Open Effects Tab
- Keyframe Transparency 0%
- Keyframe it again 100%
- Keyframe it again 100%
- Keyframe it one last time 0%
- Right Click Keyframe and Set Ease In/Out
- Right Click Keyframe and Set Ease In/Out
- Right Click Keyframe and Set Ease In/Out
- Right Click Keyframe and Set Ease In/Out
- Make sure I dont change duration of the text, or else I can repeat
  whole process again.
```

Is there no easy way to do this in premiere pro CC?

I know its supposed to be very flexible and fit everyones needs, but I really just want a simple fade effect for the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can set a default transition that uses the ctrl-d key combo. I believe it's set by default to crossfade, which I use. You click your clip, control-d and it'll put the fade in and out on the item.

You can change the default transition in the preferences.

It really is simple.

For bonus points, Control-shift-d works for audio.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Premiere Pro has a cross-dissolve effect.  You can select it as Effects->Video Transitions->Cross Dissolve.